# EsLint gives me error "Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when writing a valid tuple type

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, tuples, eslint

This is an example, I think it's a valid tuple types

```
export type SomeType = [ string, boolean ]
```

I don't know why eslint gives me this error

[image]

Comment: that file is only one line, and I'm not trying to map at all, can you elaborate more what you define as 'spesific'

Comment: @Andy no, that is an error message from ESLint *trying to parse the file*. It means that there is a problem in ESLint itself. The error ESLint threw was "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". So, it is not a problem that can be found within OP's code but how it's handled.

Comment: Try to restart your IDE or otherwise do something that restarts eslint.

Comment: This is a bug in the typescript eslint parser.
Update @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser to a more recent version

Comment: @Michael2 updating `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` totally did it!